# Get position of activity in split screen

Tags: android, layout

How can I get position of activity in split screen?

I need to check if acitivty is in top part of screen to show or hide statusbar padding. When device is landscape, there both apps have statusbar.

How can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using absolute location of thew `View`. You can check location (top over bottom). From you code, find main content `View` and then.

```
public static boolean isOnTopScreen(@NonNull View content) {
   final int[] location = new int[2];
   content.getLocationOnScreen(location);

   return location[1] < 
              (getScreenHeight() / 2);
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem()
               .getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```